# Sort an unsorted array with Closures

Tags: swift2

```
let unsortedArray = [98,23,643,678,2,568,1,234,556,4] {
    (first:Int , second:Int) -> Bool in 

    if first < second {
        return true
    } else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Above code is to sort an unsorted array with Swift 2 and Xcode 7.3.

I want to know how can i print the result?

Comment: I want to learn closure and do it with closure

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is:

```
let unsortedArray = [98, 23, 643, 678, 2, 568, 1, 234, 556, 4]
let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort() { (first: Int, second: Int) -> Bool in
    if first < second {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

print("\(sortedArray)")
```

Note, in Swift 2.3 that's `sort`, but in Swift 3, it is now called `sorted`.

---

By the way, this can be simplified:

```
let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort { (first: Int, second: Int) -> Bool in
    return first < second
}
```

Or, further simplified to use anonymous closure arguments:

```
let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort {
    return $0 < $1
}
```

Which because there is a single expression inside the closure, you can further simply to:

```
let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort { $0 < $1 }
```

Or, further simplified to:

```
let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort(<)
```

Or, because the elements of the array, `Int` types, conform to `Comparable`, you can omit the closure entirely and use a different `sort` method that takes no parameters at all:

```
let sortedArray = unsortedArray.sort()
```

Note, this requires that the elements of the array have:

> The less-than operator (`func <`) defined in
>   the `Comparable` conformance is a
>   [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_order#Strict_weak_orderings)
>   over the elements in `self`.